# Trying to understand RC circuit behavior with a square wave input

Tags: capacitor, square

Here's a circuit i built to play around with capacitor and try to understand how they work :
[image]

In the real circuit and the spice simulation i get the same voltage spike on positive side of the capacitor which i don't understand :

[image]

I would expect the "capa" node to stay at 5v, not jump to 10v on signal rise and fall to 0 on signal fall.

Comment: Looks to me like you picked a diode with some capacitance to it. Look at its Cjo and tell us what that value is. Then also try a 1N4148 (which has rather low Cjo) and see what you get. After trying the 1N4148 add a capacitor around the 1N4148 and make it something like 1 nF. See what happens.

Comment: @periblepsis 756 pF in the model. Reducing it to 0 pF I get the behavior the OP expected. 756 pF is enough to let 5 mA current flow both ways through it with the rise and fall times the pulse has.

Comment: @GodJihyo Yeah. The RC decay there looks as though 1 tau would be nearing 1 us or so. (I was guessing 5 us for 5 tau.) So that value makes sense. And yeah, now that I look I can see the 10 ns rise and fall there. Very short. Lengthening the rise and fall would lower the peaks.

Comment: @periblepsis You might want to go ahead and make that an answer then. Replacing the diode with a 756 pF cap gives the same output.

Comment: @GodJihyo I may. Other things ahead of me at this time, though. It will be hours from now by then. So feel free. You write well and I don't care about points here. So it's no nevermind for me. I'm just drinking coffee before heading out.

Comment: Thank you very much, your answers helped me a lot.

Comment: @Benoit When you see something like this behavior, an RC decay like that, then work out its timing and look for resistors and capacitors! In this case, you can see that it is entirely damped out by 5 us. I divide that by 5 (\$5\tau\$ is enough for an RC to completely decay out) so I got \$\tau\approx 1\:\mu\text{s}\$. There's a prominent resistor there, so divide the time by the resistance and you get \$\approx 1\:\text{nF}\$. Well, your explicit cap was too large for that. Had to be somewhere else. Just a simulation so not in the scope probe. Must be in the diode, then.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The diode you are using has a junction capacitance of 756 pF. So at DC it acts like a diode, only allowing current to flow in one direction, but for a fast changing voltage such as pulse edges it allows current to flow both ways.

What happens is that when the pulses are high the diode allows them to charge the 3.3 \$\mu\$F capacitor with a DC voltage, after enough cycles have passed for the circuit to stabilize, it will have a little under 5 VDC across it. This is why the output waveform is offset by ~5 V.

At this point each new pulse will see both the capacitor and the diode as close to a short circuit on the rising and falling edges. This will cause ~5 mA to flow in the circuit on each transition (5 V / 1k\$\Omega\$) and this current will drop +5 V across the resistor on positive going transitions and -5 V on negative transitions. The voltage at **capa** is then the resistor voltage added to the DC voltage on the capacitor, so the peaks go from roughly 10 V to 0 V.

Using a low capacitance diode or changing the capacitance in the model for the one you are using will make the circuit work the way you expected it to.

Comment: I'm sorry but thinking back about it there is still something i don't understand, i thought a voltage drop would always lower voltage, how can the resistor voltage drop add up to the capacitor voltage to make 10v ?

Comment: @Benoit the voltage drop has a polarity depending on the direction of the current in the resistor, when the pulse goes high, the polarity of the voltage across the resistor is in the same direction as the voltage across the cap so they add, 5+5=10, when the pulse goes low the resistor voltage is the opposite polarity of the cap so they subtract, 5-5=0.

Answer (score 1):

You'll get the answer you expect if you move the resistor to between the voltage source and diode.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I managed to understand precisely what's happening using everycircuit (i don't have a paid subscription, so i can't share the circuit)

To make things clearer i have lowered the 3.3uf capacitor (let's call it C1) to the same value of the diode, otherwise everycircuit does not show the (+) and (-) signs on the diode capacitor plates.

1. Output is at steady 5v C1 has charged through the diode capacitor (which has also picked up some charge) and through the diode itself
   [image]
2. when the falling edge of the signal occurs, the diode capacitor allow C1 to loose some charge, and it change polarity in the process
   [image]
3. finally when the rising edge occurs the diode capacitor discharge, it's voltage adding with the source, C1 charge again and the process repeat
   [image]